Unable to perform Multi team scheduling with parameterized
With parameterized scheduler plugin, I'm unable to perform multiple team for a single job scheduling.
Ex. Team A comes and scheduled a taskA by its building the JobA
My jenkinsfile trigger with the cron section is updated automatically by a script  :
triggers { parameterizedCron('''
  05 20 20 10 * %HOST_GRP=lab_1
''')

Another Team B comes and schedules the same taskA, building the same JobA.
triggers {
parameterizedCron('''
  05 20 20 10 * %HOST_GRP=lab_2
''')

It just deletes the previous schedule made by Team A and schedules the one by Team B.
All I want is to accumulate the schedulements made by any team. I have have Schedule Build Plugin but its not automated.
